# CORS error requesting php file on NGINX

Tags: php, nginx

I am making a POST request to NGINX but getting a CORS error:

Failed to load https://knode.work/save.php: Response to preflight 
request doesn't pass access control check: No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the 
requested resource. Origin 'https://www.knode.io' 
is therefore not allowed access.

On NGINX I have this in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
location / {
     # First attempt to serve request as file, then
     # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

     add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
  }

location ~ \.php$ {
     include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

     add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;

  }
```

MORE INFO:

1. I've updated the NGINX configuration file.  Please see the Gist at https://gist.github.com/jxxcarlson/c17f9d89e06f5804170a0e44236b9d9a
2. NGINX is not sending back the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header: http://noteimages.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/Screenshot%202018-08-13%2008.38.52.png

Comment: Are you sure the call is matching on the enclosing server block? Be great to see the rest of your config, if you can share it.

Comment: It could very well be wrong -- I am new at this.  Here is gist with `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`: 

https://gist.github.com/jxxcarlson/c17f9d89e06f5804170a0e44236b9d9a

Thanks so much for looking at this!

Comment: I've updated the `nginx` configuration and also the Gist in the previous comment.  Still no change. I believe that the problem is specific to requests for *.php files.  There is some discussion of this online, but no good answers that I can find so far.

Comment: `sites-available/default` — is that for knode.work or www.knode.io?

Comment: That is for knode.work -- the NGINX server with PHP

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that one needs to install `nginx-extras`:

`apt-get install nginx-extras`

then configure `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` using `more_set_headers` instead of `add_headers`, as in the listing below.  With these changes, there are no CORS errors.

```
location ~ \.php$ {

    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin';
        more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD';
        more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000';
        more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true';
        more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization';
        more_set_headers 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8';
        more_set_headers 'Content-Length: 0';
        return 204;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why configure  ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {  if he is sending POST?

Comment: cause it's preflight request?